# GL_BYTE normals not interpreted properly in Android shader

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

My shader works GREAT on iOS and Win32. The problem is Android. All devices really botch the normals if I send them as GL_BYTE. If I convert them to GL_FLOAT, everything's peachy.

```
glVertexAttribPointer(program->slots[Shaders::A_NORMAL_SLOT], 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, frame->normals);

glVertexAttribPointer(program->slots[Shaders::A_NORMAL_SLOT], 3, GL_BYTE, GL_TRUE, 0, frame->normals);
```

and YES, 'frame->normals' is of type float* in the first example, and of type char* in the second example. Like I said, this exact same code works great on iOS/Win32.

What's going on here? Is this some kind of Android bug that it won't accept byte normals?

My shader, Vertex:

```
uniform mat3 normal_matrix;
uniform mat4 mvp_matrix;
uniform vec3 u_lightpos;
uniform vec3 u_eyepos;
uniform vec4 u_color;

attribute vec4 a_vertex;
attribute vec3 a_normal;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord0;
attribute vec4 a_color;

varying vec2 v_texcoord0;
varying vec3 v_viewDir;
varying vec3 v_lightDir;
varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec4 v_color;

void main( void )
{
   vec4 fvObjectPosition = mvp_matrix * (a_vertex);

   v_viewDir  = u_eyepos;
   v_lightDir = u_lightpos;

   v_normal         = normalize(normal_matrix * a_normal);
   v_color = u_color * a_color;
   v_texcoord0    = a_texcoord0.xy;
   gl_Position = fvObjectPosition;
}
```

Fragment:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif
uniform vec4 u_specular;
uniform vec4 u_diffuse;
uniform float u_specularpower;

uniform sampler2D t_texture0;

varying vec2 v_texcoord0;
varying vec3 v_viewDir;
varying vec3 v_lightDir;
varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec4 v_color;

void main( void )
{
   float fNDotL           = dot( v_normal, v_lightDir ); 
   vec3  fvReflection     = normalize( ( ( 2.0 * v_normal ) * fNDotL ) - v_lightDir );

   vec4  fvBaseColor      = v_color * texture2D( t_texture0, v_texcoord0 );

   vec4  fvTotalDiffuse   = vec4((u_diffuse * fNDotL).xyz, 1.0) * fvBaseColor;
   vec4  fvTotalSpecular  = u_specular * ( pow( max( 0.0, dot( fvReflection, -v_viewDir ) ), u_specularpower ) );

   gl_FragColor = vec4(( fvBaseColor + fvTotalDiffuse + fvTotalSpecular ).xyz, v_color.w);       
}
```

Comment: do you have access to another device(to test the app)? maybe it is device specific problem ...

Comment: So far, I've tested it on about 5+ devices, all very popular (Samsung Galaxy series, HTC, etc.) with the same issue. If I don't normalize the output, I get the same result on all devices, but if I GL_TRUE for normalization (as shown above), I get sliiiightly better results on a Galaxy Vibrant. I suspect this may be a driver issue, or even something OS-level with the OpenGL implementation, but I can't believe it has gone undetected for so long.